# Diagnosis of normality assumption and fitting linear regression in R

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, assumptions, normality-assumption

I am using the data `veteran` from  `R` package `survival`.

How can I  diagnose the normality assumption about `time`? Should I need to perform a linear regression to measure the dependency of `time` on `age` and `karno`?

Are the following commands all to answer the question? or Do I need to add more information?

```
   #diagnoses normality assumption about 'time'.
   shapiro.test(veteran$time)
   qqnorm(veteran$time)
   qqline(veteran$time)

   #perform a linear regression
   with(veteran,lm(time~age+karno))
   with(veteran,cor.test(time,age))
   with(veteran,cor.test(time,karno))
```

#### EDIT :

I want to diagnose the normality assumption. How can I do this for the above data?
And for diagnosing the normality assumption, I chose `R` software.
So my question involves both diagnosie the normality assumption and R syntax.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is entirely about which software syntax is appropriate. See the help for more advice if unclear. 

Comment: Btw, none of these methods answer the question about normality of the errors.

Comment: @NickCox the first two questions in the body of the post -- "*How can I diagnose the normality assumption about time? Should I need to perform a linear regression to measure the dependency of time on age and karno?*" seem completely on topic to me. They're not directly questions about syntax but about statistical issues.

Comment: @Glen_b Why then ask "Are the following commands all to answer the question"?

Comment: I didn't say there weren't any syntax questions. There are statistical questions - ones which can be addressed - and so the question looks to be on topic for CV, to my eyes. But even the directly R questions seem to be borderline (since they're about implementation\* of a statistical calculation). -- * not useful, perhaps (though addressing why is again a statistical issue) -- I think even that arguably falls under the last topic in the list of what's on topic in the help.

Comment: It seems that the title means diagnosis of assumptions of the linear model (normal distributed residuals), while the body means asks about diagnosis about the response itself. Linear model assumption has nothing about the response distribution itself, but the normal residuals. But maybe response distribution is your particular study in your project?

Comment: I agree with @Glen_b .

Comment: user2983722 As above, your question has produced quite different interpretations. Please clarify: Do you want general advice on assessing normality in a linear regression context? specific advice geared to R syntax? specific advice geared to the dataset you refer to? Why you suppose a linear regression with time as response makes sense, any way? In short, precisely what is "the question" you are addressing?

Comment: @NickCox Perhaps, i couldn't able to express  what i actually want. Please, see my edit.

Comment: As @Michael Mayer hinted, any normality assumption in regression is about the errors, not the original data, and as such is best examined by looking at the residuals from a (serious) model.